# How to rejoin domain when trust relationship is lost

Tags: powershell, remoting

I have a number of virtual machines which have snapshots applied by using a PowerShell script. Occasionally, the virtual machines lose their "trust relationship" with the domain. This breaks the script as I can no longer use PowerShell remoting to get into the machines and configure them.

How can I *remotely* reset the trust relationship of these virtual machines? Perhaps there are possibilities for rejoining the domain that don't involve remoting?

Any alternate solutions to manually rejoining the domain require logging in to the computer and doing this locally. I haven't found anything that can do this otherwise.

So far, I've attempted to put together a script that simply remotes into the box as the local administrator:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Administrator", $password)
$sesh = new-pssession -computername "theMachine" -credential $cred
```

At this point, I was hoping to use PowerShell to reset the password or something like that to reset the domain trust relationship. However, this results in an error on the last line: `Access is Denied`.

I don't think you can use the local administrator account with PowerShell remoting. Is there any other way I can remotely get a virtual machine that has lost its domain trust relationship to rejoin the domain?

Comment: Your question is a very good one - but I think it would be more on topic in one of Stack Overflow sister sites, more specifically [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). Think of it as a Stack Overflow that's more server and infrastructure oriented. Your question may well be on topic here if you try to solve your problem with code, though you'd have to at least show us what coding solution you've tried so far in that case.

Comment: @Renan Good point. I'll post on Server Fault. I'll add an attempted coding solution now.

Comment: I see. In that case, +1.

Comment: I believe this Powershell cmdlet will fix a system with domain trust issues: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849751.aspx Also you can set a reg key prior to creating snapshots to DisablePasswordChange on the machine account to prevent this from occuring (see  https://rhyous.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/virtual-machines-snapshots-domain-membership-and-trust-relationship/ )

Answer (score 2):

Interesting a problem. Would a combination of `PSExec` and `netdom` work? I don't have a VM with broken trust relationship, so I can't test the idea.

Anyway, `PSExec` has parameters `-u` and `-p` for username and password. Make sure you know a local administrator account. Passing its credentials to `PSExec` should provide a remote shell even with broken trust relationship. `Netdom.exe` or a Powershell script can be used to re-join the computer to the domain.

Another an option would be changing the policy for computer accounts. A GPO that sets "Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Domain member: Maximum machine account password age" to 0 would set the computer account password never to expire. This might rise some security issues, though.

**Edit**

Use psexec to open a shell session. Like so,

`psexec -u computer\administrator -p password \\computer cmd`

After you got the shell, try and experiment with netdom commands. Remove the computer from the domain and add it to the domain. Netdom [join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788049.aspx) and netdom [remove](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788074.aspx) support credential passing, so supply valid domain account credentials. After you know the exact command syntax, save the values to a script file and launch it with psexec like so,

`psexec -u computer\administrator -p password \\computer c:\myScript.cmd`

Comment: OK, here's what I'm trying: `psexec -u "Administrator" -p "<password" \\theMachine netdom join theMachine /Domain:mydomain.local`. This results in an error: `The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed`. It's still trying to use the domain account I guess? What's wrong with that line?

Comment: I see your edit. I've tried that line as well with the same result.

Comment: How about `-u computername\administrator`?

Comment: If anyone tries the running psexec as above (which is correct, especially prefixing the username with the machinename) and gets the error `Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer` there is some sort of feature change with psexec 2.34+ and the command now requires `-i` argument. New example usage: `psexec -i -u computer\administrator -p password \\computer cmd`. Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/233240/logon-failure-the-user-has-not-been-granted-the-re.html